# $\langle Av,Aw\rangle=\langle v,w\rangle$,$\det(A)=1$ proof verification

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the field $K$, with a non-degenerate scalar product $\langle ,\rangle$. If $A:V\to V$ is a linear map such that:
>
> $\langle Av,Aw\rangle=\langle v,w\rangle$
>
> for all $v,w\in V$, show that $\det(A)=+1$ OR $\det (A)=-1$

**SOLUTION**. Fix $w$. Then for all $v$ in $V$ we have

$\langle v,w\rangle=\langle Av,Aw\rangle=\langle v,A^tAw\rangle$.

Thus

$\langle v,w-A^tAw\rangle=0$

So $A^tA=I$ because the scar product is non-degenerate. Therefore,

$1=\det(I)=\det(A^tA)=\det(A^t)\det(A)$,

but $\det(A^t)=\det(A)$, so we conclude that $\det(A)=1$ or $-1$. In the general case we also have $A^*A=AA^*=I$ (where $A^*$ is the transpose of the operator). If $J$ represents the scalar product, then $\langle Av,w\rangle=\langle v,A^*w\rangle$ so that $A^tJ=JA^t$ where $A^t$ is the transpose matrix of $A$. Hence

$$\det(A^t)=\det(A^*)$$

which implies that $\det(A^*)^2=1$.

**Solutions Manual for Lang's Linear Algebra,Rami Sharkarchi.**

---

**Questions**

1. Since by assumption we have $\langle Av,Aw\rangle=\langle v,w\rangle$ for all $v,w\in V$. Why is it not straightforward from the definition that $A=I$, the identity matrix?
2. "If $J$ represents the scalar product, then $\langle
       Av,w\rangle=\langle v,A^*w\rangle$ so that $A^tJ=JA^t$ where $A^t$
   is the transpose matrix of $A$. Hence $\det(A^t)=\det(A^*)$" What is the idea behind this proof? Is $A^*$ not already the transpose matrix? Does the operator transpose not equal the matrix transpose? What is the meaning of this last proof?

Comment: Why would $A=I$ follow from $\langle Av,Aw\rangle=\langle v,w\rangle$? Tell us your thought process.

Comment: For (1), if $Av=v$ for all $v$ then $A=I$ by definition. But if one only assumes $\langle Av,Aw\rangle=\langle v, w\rangle$, one *cannot* conclude that $A=I$.

Comment: @anon I thought that for $\langle Av,Aw \rangle=\langle v,w \rangle$ the A operator needs to be the unitary matrix that would assure that $Av=v$.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 Then $\det(A)=\det(I)=1$. This is not allowing me to see the idea behind the proof provided by the book.

Comment: Well, a matrix is called unitary if $\langle Av,Aw\rangle=\langle v,w\rangle$, but you seem to be saying it must be the *identity* matrix. But *why* do you think that? With real inner product spaces, since $\langle v,w\rangle=\|v\|\|w\|\cos\theta$, all the condition means is that $A$ preserves distances and angles between vectors - i.e. it is a rotation, which clearly *does* preserve distances and angles but also clearly is *not* necessarily the identity matrix!

Comment: @anon                  I have not covered unitary matrices still. I am going to investigate on them. That might be the reason why the answer seems to me so straightforward. The only example that comes to my head that has the neutrality property is the identity matrix.

Comment: I just gave you more examples: rotations.

Comment: An example is *not* a proof.

Comment: @anon           I have seen rotation but I have never thought of them like that before.

Comment: The conclusion " or $\det(A)=-1$" gives you a hint that one should not expect that $A=I$ is the only case.

Comment: Also, one can think about the 1D case: $Ax=-x$.

Comment: "Does the operator transpose not equal the matrix transpose? " An operator and its representation matrix are two different concepts. They are not "equal".

Comment: @anon If an unitary matrix needs to comply with $A^tA=I$. How can the author conclude from $\langle v,w-A^tAw\rangle=0$, that $A=I$? Why not other unitary matrix as the rotation matrix?

Comment: $\langle v,(I-A^tA)w\rangle=0$ for all $v$ implies $(I-A^tA)w=0$. 
If $(I-A^tA)w=0$ for all $w$ then $I-A^tA=0$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Consider the matrix 
   $$
   \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0}
   $$ 
   which has the property you mention, but is not the identity.
2. The "In the general case" claim appears to be false, for the matrix
   $$
   A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1}
   $$ 
   where it's not true that the square of the matrix $A^t$ is the identity.

Comment: I post here the same observation of above. If an unitary matrix needs to comply with $A^tA=I$. How can the author conclude from $\langle v,w-A^tAw\rangle=0$, that $A=I$? Why not other unitary matrix as the rotation matrix?

Comment: The author doesn't conclude that $A = I$; the author concludes that $A^t A = I$, which is correct.