# If $A: V\to V$ is a linear map such that $\langle Av, Aw\rangle=\langle v, w\rangle$ for all $v, w\in V$, show that $\det(A)=\pm 1$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the field $K$, with a nondegenerate scalar product$\langle, \rangle$. If $A: V\to V$ is a linear map such that $\langle Av, Aw\rangle=\langle v, w\rangle$ for all $v, w\in V$, show that $\det(A)=\pm 1$.

The solution said:

In the general case we also have $A^*A=AA^*=I$ (where $A^*$ is the transpose of the operator). If $J$ represents the scalar product, then $\langle Av,w\rangle=\langle v,A^*w\rangle$ so that $A^tJ=JA^t$ where $A^t$ is the transpose matrix of $A$. Hence $\det(A^t)=\det(A^*)$, which implies that $\det(A^*)^2=1$.

I don't understand why in solution, $\langle Av,w\rangle=\langle v,A^*w\rangle$ can show that $A^tJ=JA^t$? And why then $\det(A^t)=\det(A^*)$?

(I find a post [$\langle Av,Aw\rangle=\langle v,w\rangle$,$\det(A)=1$ proof verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380342/langle-av-aw-rangle-langle-v-w-rangle-deta-1-proof-verification) asked about the same problem, but didn't address the same question of this problem.)
[image]

Comment: The most basic issue: I think you've overloaded $A$.  If you call your linear operator on a coordinate vector space $A$, and then select a basis appropriate to the bilinear form $\mathbf B$ and you have $A\mathbf B = \mathbf B Q$.

Comment: @Cathy I suspect that in this (strangely written) solution that you found, $J$ is defined to be a matrix such that, relative to some basis, the scalar product can be written as $\langle x,y \rangle = x^TJy$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusing part is that in this solution there is only one notation being used for two different inner products. Let's say that $V = \mathbb{R}^n$. Then an abstract vector $v \in V$ or an abstract linear operator $A \colon V \to V$ may be treated as column vector $[v] \in \mathbb{K}^n$ or a matrix $[A] \in \operatorname{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})$. Furthermore, when $(-)^T$ denotes the transpose of a vector or matrix, then we have a standard inner product I'll denote by $(v \cdot u) = [v]^T [u]$. For each linear operator $A \colon V \to V$, we *define* its adjoint with respect to $(- \cdot -)$ to be the operator $A^T \colon V \to V$ satisfying
$$ (A u \cdot v) = (u \cdot A^T v) \text{ for all } u, v \in V.$$
One can prove that the adjoint exists and is unique. Furthermore, applying the definition of $(- \cdot -)$ to the equation above, we get $[u]^T [A]^T [v] = [u] [A^T] [v]$ for all $u, v \in V$, and so it turns out that the *matrix* $[A^T]$ of the adjoint is equal to the conjugate-transpose of the matrix $[A]$. (This distinction is subtle, but important for what is to come).

---

Now, suppose we have any other inner product $\langle -, - \rangle \colon V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ defined on $V$. We can again define the adjoint $A^\dagger$ of a linear operator $A \colon V \to V$, this time with respect to the new inner product, to be the unique linear operator satisfying

$$ \langle A u, v \rangle = \langle u, A^\dagger v \rangle \text{ for all } u, v \in V. $$

The crucial point is that $A^T \neq A^\dagger$ in general: adjoints with repsect to *different* inner products are different. How can we relate them to each other? The standard way to do this is to express the new inner product $\langle -, - \rangle$ in terms of the old inner product $(- \cdot -)$: there is a unique linear operator $J \colon V \to V$ such that
$$ \langle u, v \rangle = (u \cdot J v) \text{ for all } u, v \in V.$$
If all we're starting with is the standard basis of $V = \mathbb{R}^n$ then, we can calculate any new inner product $\langle u, v \rangle$ by working out the column vectors $[u]$, $[v]$, and the matrix $[J]$, and then doing
$$ \langle u, v \rangle = (u \cdot J v) = [u]^T [J] [v]. $$
What is the relationship between $A^\dagger$ and $A^T$? Just by manipulating the defining equations, we have
$$ \begin{aligned}
\langle Au, v \rangle = (Au \cdot Jv) = (u \cdot A^T J v) &&&\text{ for all } u, v \in V, \text{ and } \\
\langle u, A^\dagger v \rangle = (u \cdot J A^\dagger v) &&&\text{ for all } u, v \in V.
\end{aligned}$$
Since these are equal, we have the relationship $J A^\dagger = A^T J$.

---

Having said all of that, the proof is confusing when it should be simple. We can work with *any* inner product $\langle -, - \rangle \colon V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$, and with any operator $A \colon V \to V$ which is *unitary* with respect to that inner product, meaning $\langle Au, Av \rangle = \langle u, v \rangle$ for all $u, v \in V$. The key point is realising that being unitary is equivalent to the condition $A^\dagger = A^{-1}$. The proof should proceed in simple steps:

1. Determine that for a unitary operator $A$, we have $A A^\dagger = I$.
2. Determine that for *any* operator $A$, we have $\det(A^\dagger) = \det(A)$.
3. Conclude that for a unitary operator, $\det(A)^2 = 1$.

Parts 1 and 3 should be easy, straight from the definition. Part 2 is more tricky if your definition of determinants uses matrices, and this is where we have to go via the standard inner product $(- \cdot -)$, by writing $A^\dagger = J^{-1} A^T J$, applying $\det$ to get $\det(A^\dagger) = \det(A^T)$, and then using the fact that $[A^T] = [A]^T$ to get
$$ \det(A^\dagger) = \det(J^{-1} A^T J) =\det(A^T) = \det([A^T]) = \det([A]^T) = \det([A]) = \det(A), $$
where in the second-last equals we have used the fact that the determinant of the transpose of a matrix is equal to the determinant of the matrix.

There are other ways to prove part 2 if you have alternative definitions of the determinant that don't require going via a matrix, but I suspect this is the definition of the determinant used in the book.

Comment: Thank you so much! It takes me a while to understand this answer.   It really makes things clear, but I still has few points don't understand (1) why there is a unique linear operator $J \colon V \to V$ s.t. $\langle u, v \rangle = (u \cdot J v)$? (2). Why  $(Au \cdot Jv) = (u \cdot A^T J v)$ (3) $\det(A)^2 = 1$ holds for any inner product or only for dot product (4) I don't understand how part 2 proved in the simpler proof.

Comment: @Cathy (1) Assume that $J$ and $J'$ are two linear operators satisfying that equation, then $0 = \langle u, v \rangle - \langle u, v \rangle = (u \cdot Jv) - (u \cdot J' v) = (u \cdot (J - J')v)$ for all $u, v \in V$. Since $(- \cdot -)$ is nondegenerate, by the "for all $u$" condition we have that $(J - J')v = 0$ for all $v \in V$, which implies that $J = J'$. (2) That is the definition of the tranpose $A^T$, the first centred equation in my answer. (3) $\det(A)^2 = 1$ will hold for any inner product, meaning $\langle -, - \rangle$ is symmetric and positive-definite. (4) can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

Let $B=A^TA$. Then $\langle v, Bw\rangle=\langle v, w\rangle$. Hence $\langle v, Bw-w\rangle=0$ for every $v, w$. Take $v=Bw-w$. You get $||v||=0$, so $v=0$. Thus for every $w, Bw=w$, so $B=A^TA=I$. Since $\det(A)=\det(A^T)$, we have  $\det(A^2)=1$, so
$\det(A)=\pm 1$.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand the $J$ part in the solution.

Comment: There is no $J$ in this answer. What is $J$?

Comment: I mean in the solution I gave in the post.

Comment: I do not understand what  $J$ is there too.

Comment: You wrote: "If $J$ represents the scalar product". What does that mean?

Comment: I don't know, this solution is so confusing. It comes from official solution of Serge Lang's linear algebra. I've added the screen shot of the whole solution.

Comment: I understand now: the scalar product in your question is not standard, it is $<x,y>=x^TJy$ where $J$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix. What is confusing about Lang's text is various types of transposes that he seems to use. There is the standard transpose, the transpose corresponding to the non-standard scalar product, and one more that I still cannot figure out.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is a linear operator on a coordinate vector space $\mathbb F^n$.  When you say the matrix $J$ 'represents' the non-degerate scalar product, I interpret this to mean

there is some basis chosen and given by the hyper-vector  $\mathbf B$
(this is also a square matrix since we are dealing with a coordinate vector space)  and

$j_{i,k} = \langle \mathbf b_i,\mathbf b_k\rangle$
now consider the effect of $A$ operating on $\mathbf B$
$A\mathbf B = \mathbf B Q$
taking determinants of each side we see $\det\big(A\big) = \det\big(Q\big)$

so it suffices to prove  $\det\big(Q\big)\in\{-1,+1\}$

Consider $v,v' \in V$
$v = \mathbf B\mathbf x$ and $v' =\mathbf B y$;
$\mathbf w = Q\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf z = Q\mathbf y$
$\langle A v, Av'\rangle$
$=\langle A\mathbf B\mathbf x\mathbf , A\mathbf B\mathbf y\rangle$
$=\langle \mathbf B (Q\mathbf x), \mathbf B(Q\mathbf y)\rangle$
$=\langle \mathbf B \mathbf w, \mathbf B\mathbf z\rangle$
$=\langle \sum_{k=1}^n  \mathbf b_k w_k , \sum_{i=1}^n  \mathbf b_i z_i\rangle$
$=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n w_kz_i \langle  \mathbf b_k  ,   \mathbf b_i \rangle$
$=\mathbf w^TJ\mathbf z$
$=\mathbf x^T Q^T JQ\mathbf y$

and by nearly identical calculation
$\mathbf x^T J\mathbf y = \langle  v, v'\rangle =  \langle  Av, Av'\rangle=\mathbf x^T Q^T J Q\mathbf y$

the choice of $v, v'$ were arbitrary, so we may run the above argument on $n$ linearly independent vectors in $V$ which gives
$X^TJX = X^T Q^T JQX \implies J = Q^T J Q$
so $Q$ is a **stabilizer** for $J$  and being non-degenerate $\det\big(J\big) \neq 0$  thus
$\det\big(J\big)=\det\big(Q^T\big)\det\big(J\big) \det\big(Q\big)\implies \det\big(Q\big)^2 =1\implies \det\big(Q\big) \in \{-1,+1\}$